# npm install npm@latest -g

Tags: npm, terminal

I am just starting out in programming. I am trying to upgrade `npm` using

```
npm install npm@latest -g
```

I couldn't understand the terminal output, as in the screenshot below. The status wasn't changing.

What button should I press? Should I just wait? Or what should I do?

I know this is an absolutely naive question. But I do not know how to resolve it, or even find the doc or reference to solve it.

Is it to do with VIM or Linux, or where can I learn about that systematically?

[image]

Comment: Looks like it's installing

Comment: It's just downloading

Comment: yeah..I installed it just now and try to test how to upgrade, and encounter this..is that something optional..I mean `sill` and `install`?

Comment: @Gabriele B-David I realize..but occur another `npm ERR! Darwin 16.4.0...`, I think I should do it from the begining again..

Comment: I just realised that this may be due to the order of your parameters in the script. You should try writing it like this `npm install -g npm@latest`